# SQL pagination for posts and 3 latest comments for each posts

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query which selects up to 3 comments (if present) for each post:

```
SELECT p.*, c.* 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON (p.post_id=c.post_id) 
AND c.comment_id > 
   (SELECT comment_id FROM comments 
    WHERE post_id=p.post_id ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 3
   )
```

I'd also like to introduce pagination over the posts. For example, I'd like to limit for only 10 posts for each page.

**Just for clarification** - I mean 10 DISTINCT posts for pagination, not 3 posts in a result query and 3 comments for each post. I mean 10 distinct posts * comments(up to 3 for each post) for these posts.

How can I introduce pagination over the posts in this query?

**One more solution:**

Also, I have found one more solution for this task:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM posts
    LIMIT 0, 10
) p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT c.*, 
        @rownumber := CASE WHEN @post_id = post_id THEN @rownumber + 1 ELSE 1 END AS n,
        @post_id := post_id
    FROM comments c,
    (SELECT @rownumber := 0, @post_id := 0) r    
    ORDER BY post_id DESC
) c ON p.post_id = c.post_id
WHERE c.post_id IS NULL OR n BETWEEN 1 and 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Basic answer

The same syntax you are using in the **`SELECT`** for your comments:

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

However, your query has the error of using `LIMIT 3, 1` (which returns only the fourth row) instead of `LIMIT 0, 3` or `LIMIT 3`.

## Extended answer

This is not an easy query to write, since it is very complex, but I wrote a simpler version below that does what you want. This would be a lot easier if you wanted to select 30 comments, with a maximum of 3 comments per post, but this is obviously not what you want to do.

Basically, the query returns the first 10 `posts`, with 2 fields for each comment (`comments.id` and `comments.comment`), bringing that to a total of 6 fields for the three comments.

How it does this is by using three `LEFT JOIN`s with the comments table with each having a different `id` from the previous `LEFT JOIN`. This creates up to three rows for each post, so we then use `GROUP BY p.id` to merge them all into one row.
The query also uses `ORDER BY p.id ASC`, since using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is unpredictable (the database engine will in most case internally apply an `ORDER BY` clause to the results).

> **Note:** If you have an `INDEX` on `comments.post_id`, this query will be extremely fast.

### MySQL query

```
SELECT p.*,
       c1.id AS comment1_id, c1.comment AS comment1,
       c2.id AS comment2_id, c2.comment AS comment2,
       c3.id AS comment3_id, c3.comment AS comment3

FROM posts AS p

LEFT JOIN comments AS c1 ON c1.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN comments AS c2 ON c2.post_id = p.id AND c2.id <> c1.id
LEFT JOIN comments AS c3 ON c3.post_id = p.id AND c3.id <> c1.id AND c3.id <> c2.id

GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

### Result

```
| id |       post | comment1_id |  comment1 | comment2_id |  comment2 | comment3_id |  comment3 |
|----|------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|  1 |  Post 1... |           1 | Comment 1 |           2 | Comment 2 |      (null) |    (null) |
|  2 |  Post 2... |           3 | Comment 3 |           8 | Comment 8 |           9 | Comment 9 |
|  3 |  Post 3... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
|  4 |  Post 4... |           4 | Comment 4 |           5 | Comment 5 |           7 | Comment 7 |
|  5 |  Post 5... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
|  6 |  Post 6... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
|  7 |  Post 7... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
|  8 |  Post 8... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
|  9 |  Post 9... |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
| 10 | Post 10... |           6 | Comment 6 |      (null) |    (null) |      (null) |    (null) |
```

> See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/182db/4 for an online example.

By checking the fields for `null`, you can check whether that post has a comment or not, and how many comments that post has.

> **Note:** You should stick with **UPPERCASE** for the SQL keywords, since that is the accepted industry best practise.

Comment: Thank you very much ! One more question, from the performance perspective will this query work fine or I should try to implement it in some other way ?

Comment: @alexanoid **Edit:** This should be extremely fast if `comments.id` is an `INDEX`, as it is in the example.

Comment: @alexanoid Please see the latest edit of my answer. I suddenly remembered that using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is unpredictable.

Comment: @ toothbrush, thank you very much ! Also, i have found one more solution for this task and added it into the question body. Could you please let me know what do you think about that approach ?

Comment: @alexanoid It's okay, but it internally creates 6 queries, whereas the query in my example only creates 4.

Comment: @alexanoid Actually, upon looking at it again, the other solution is very inefficient since it reads **all** the comments and searches them **all** for the `post_id`. This means that there is no room for optimisations by the database, as there are no indexes that can be used to speed up the lookup. An index means that you can find one row out of 100 trillion rows by only checking up to 47 rows.

Comment: Thanks ! Performance is the point number one for my final decision!

Comment: upvoted. Also I need additional field fore each post that has number of total comments for that post, how can I achieve this?